# Charge using 3D secure from REST apis in mobile apis

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am stuck on a issue. Might be it is not an issue. I have feature to save cards & payment using those cards. I am using laravel to create the APIs. Now we might have 3D secure card which is saved there in stripe.

So the question is how can I manage both 3D secure payment & save cards using Stripe REST apis. I can use paymentIntend & Charge from stripe. But I need in the REST apis, not from webview.
Is it possible? Or any other alternatives to complete the 3D secure payment which is in pending state.

Please help. Here is my response when I try to charge the 3D secure card -

```
{
  "id": "pi_1H5VOGIvRm4SRAz9LNjjTx6r",
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "last_payment_error": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "next_action": null,
  "status": "requires_payment_method",
  "amount": 2000,
  "amount_capturable": 0,
  "amount_received": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "cancellation_reason": null,
  "capture_method": "automatic",
  "charges": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_1H5VOGIvRm4SRAz9LNjjTx6r"
  },
  "client_secret": "pi_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "confirmation_method": "automatic",
  "created": 1594899400,
  "currency": "chf",
  "customer": "cus_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "description": null,
  "invoice": null,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "payment_method": null,
  "payment_method_options": {
    "card": {
      "installments": null,
      "network": null,
      "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
    }
  },
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
  "receipt_email": null,
  "review": null,
  "setup_future_usage": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "transfer_data": null,
  "transfer_group": null
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read all about the different ways you can save cards using the new approach here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/more-payment-scenarios

Comment: Thanks. Save card is fine, but not able to do payment using 3D secure cards from REST apis.

Comment: like some subscription or something else from backend.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.